# Javascript : cannot set property of undefined

Tags: javascript, function, typeerror

Say I have a function within a function.
I want the outer function to return the inner function.
And I want the inner function to be able to be instantiated using the "new" operator.

What I have is

```
function fun1() {
    function fun2(obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }
    return fun2;
}
```

However, I get the error "cannot set property of 'obj' undefined"

I don't know where to begin with fixing this.

Comment: How are you calling it? I can't replicate this error in the Chrome dev console

Comment: Where is the function executed? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Depending on how the function is called in strict mode, *this* may well be undefined.

Answer (score 3):

```js
function fun1() {
    function fun2(obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }
    return fun2;
}

console.log(new (fun1())('hello'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var fun1 = (function() {
    function fun2(obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }
    return fun2;
}());
```

I think this is what you're looking for.

usage:

```
var foo = new fun1(some_obj);
```